# Geometric Intuition for the Existence of Eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Is there a geometric explanation for why an eigenvector must exist for a linear transformation on a finite dimensional vector space over C?

How about for an eigenbasis from a normal transformations?

Comment: Personally I find it hard even to visualize $\mathbb{C}^2$ to begin with, so I'd be impressed if someone comes up with a good answer to this question!

Comment: A question that motivates the development of the concepts of eigenvectors and eigenvalues is this: "are there any lines that are mapped to themselves by the transformation.”